# Including 3rd party code as source vs dll

Tags: c#

There is a Github project for a C# library that I'd like to use. Is it more conventional to include the source as a separate project in my Visual Studio solution and build the dll as part of the regular compilation process, or to build a dll separately and include just that in my project reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you need to modify the source, use a DLL. Don't forget to mention the license and the source repository location (home of the Github project)

Comment: Upvoting: it was the first among similar answers.

Comment: +1. Using existing project as is - copying/merging to your own likely will be unnecessary pain down the road. Side note: reading and mentioning the license is a good start. It may already contain the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Both the options are equally valid and depends upon how often you require the change the source code.

> If you really need to change the `source code` then you should add the
>   source code to your project otherwise just adding the reference of the `dll` will save your
>   compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen both approaches.

Mostly I've included 3rd party code into the solution if I intended to modify it a little, or at least I assumed I would.

All other cases, Dll works fine.